# Get specific content in iframe without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i want to get spesific contents (all of spans in .y6) in iframe without jQuery,
How can i write it only javascript?

"**#canvas_frame**" is an iframe

```
spans = $("#canvas_frame").contents().find(".y6>span");
```

Comment: If there's a restriction on jQuery in particular, you can use sizzle.js  (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

**If the iframe is on the same domain as the parent page** you can use the iframe's contentWindow property.

Something like the below should help you out:

```
var canvasFrame = document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentWindow,
    allSpans = canvasFrame.document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    spans = [],
    i;

i = allSpans.length;
while(i--){
    if(/y6/.test(allSpans[i].parentNode.className)){
        spans.push(allSpans[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: :( it's give me an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined" error... and u forget ")" in line 9. this is all of code https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4842648/contentscript.js and error line is this: allSpans = canvasFrame.document.getElementsByTagName('span'),

Comment: have you got a page that this is running on with the original markup?

Comment: this code is running on gmail page and i still get same error :(